# Route user based on flag received from Okta Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, single-sign-on, angular8, okta

In my app when user clicks on go to login page button on `temporaryLoginPage`, the user is redirected to Okta login page. Now upon successful login, Okta shares back claims containing a flag name: `registered`. I want to route user to different pages based on the `registered` flag. The question is my application is changing scope and how to capture the info in flight and show some kind of loader on `temporaryLogin` page while the flag is being checked and when flag is read how to redirect user on the following condition:

```
registered = true // route to /home
registered = false // route to /registration
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply checks the data coming from login service after successful completion and navigate to the particular route like this Eg-

```
this.loginservice(credentials).subscribe(userData=>{
   userData.registered?
       this.router.navigate(['./home']) :
       this.router.navigate(['./registration'])
})
```

Also you can add one flag in the beginning of calling service and make it true and make this loaderFlag false in the above subscription to hide and show your loader

Answer (score 0):

You could probably create your own handler for the callback and do some logic in there. The default callback component is at https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/blob/master/packages/okta-angular/src/okta/components/callback.component.ts.